# how import works in modules imported into Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

The documentation I've read is rather hand-wavy about what exactly `import` does in Javascript, particularly in the Angular framework. I get that it imports modules from another file that has one or more `exports`.  But there are many permutations of its syntax, and not all are discussed with much detail.  I'm currently having a very hard time with the @asymmetik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster module.  When I try to compile my Angular app, I get a message reading "Can't resolve 'leaflet.markercluster' in 'C:\sca_root\city8\node_modules@asymmetrik\ngx-leaflet-markercluster\dist\leaflet-markercluster" -- this is in reference to a line that reads simply

```
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
```

This seems to me (and I know, perhaps I am making too many assumptions here) that there should be a file in that same directory named `leaflet.markercluster.js` or perhaps `leaflet.markercluster.ts` (it's Javascript, not TypeScript, so it will be the former). But there is no file named `leaflet.markercluster.js` in that directory.  These are the files in that directory:

```
leaflet-markercluster.directive.js.map
leaflet-markercluster.directive.metadata.json
leaflet-markercluster.module.d.ts
leaflet-markercluster.module.js
leaflet-markercluster.module.js.map
leaflet-markercluster.module.metadata.json
leaflet-markercluster.directive.d.ts
eaflet-markercluster.directive.js
```

Which one would that import statement import?  If not any of them, where outside this directory would it import that file from?  What other information (perhaps in tsconfig.json or angular.json) might affect where this import statement imports from?

Comment: You are uaing typescriot import in angular then: `import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';`

Comment: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/blob/master/README.md#usage

Comment: @vipulpatel Absolutely has the correct answer. Their documentation appears very appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in this case was that leaflet.markercluster ALSO needs @types installed.  i had to issue a

```
npm install @types/leaflet @types/leaflet.markercluster
```

i don't know why the error had nothing to do with @types, but this is in keeping with the soul-crushing nature of Angular development.